# A discrepancy when locations are retrieved from Geocoding API and Google maps

Tags: google-maps

I have encountered a discrepancy between Geocoding API and Google maps when checking the same locations.
I tried the following locations in Google maps:
33 Place Massena, 06000 Nice, France (as the start location)
Gare de Nice Ville, Avenue Thiers, 06000 Nice France (as the destination)
The distance is between 1.7 and 2.2 km.

[image]

However, when I used Google maps and replaced the above destination with its Geocoding API, the distance is 3.7 km
[image]
The API I used is in the following link: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Gare%20de%20Nice%20Ville,%20Avenue%20Thiers,%2006000%20Nice%20France
Please see the attached pictures for further references.

Could you please check and let me know why it is different?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is intended behavior, you should understand the difference between applying the address string and applying the coordinate.

When you apply the address string 'Gare de Nice Ville, Avenue Thiers, 06000 Nice France' the directions service will geocode it to the establishment with place ID ChIJnfu2MAbQzRIR1aBedCqfGXA.

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DGare%2520de%2520Nice%2520Ville%252C%2520Avenue%2520Thiers%252C%252006000%2520Nice%2520France

In this case the directions service will use an access point defined for this establishment. Looking at your screenshots I guess that the access point for this establishment is like shown in my screenshot

[image]

If you apply the coordinate 43.704612,7.261933 the directions service will just snap it to the nearest road. Something similar to the following request

`https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path=43.704612%2C7.261933&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

The result of the snapping to the road is shown in the following screenshot

[image]

As you can see the snapped point and the access point for establishment are different. I suppose that there are certain turn restrictions that doesn't allow to use Avenue Thiers to reach the snapped point and you make a big detour via Voie Pierre Mathis in this case.

I hope my explanation solves your doubts!